# Failed to delete the page after migration V11 -> V12

Tags: kentico

I'm using Kentico V12 now.

Yesteraday we've update our Kentico V11 to V12.
All steps successful but now, when we want to delete a page, we receive this error message into the logs :

- System    REMOVEDEPENDENCIES
- Content   DELETEDOC

Message: [SqlGenerator.GetAutomaticQuery]: Class name 'CMS.AlternativeUrl' doesn't exist.

Exception type: CMS.DataEngine.DataClassNotFoundException
Stack trace:
at CMS.DataEngine.DataClassInfoProvider.GetDataClassInfo(String name, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at CMS.DataEngine.SqlGenerator.GetAutomaticQuery(String queryFullName)
at CMS.DataEngine.QueryInfoProvider.GetQueryInfoInternal(String queryName)
at CMS.DataEngine.QueryInfoProvider.GetQueryInfo(String name, Boolean throwException)
at CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetConnectionStringName()
at CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.get_ConnectionStringName()
at CMS.DataEngine.Query.QueryBatch.<>c.b__3_0(IDataQuery q)
at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3.GetEnumerator()
at CMS.DataEngine.Query.QueryBatch.d__3.MoveNext()
at CMS.DataEngine.Query.QueryBatch.Execute()
at CMS.DataEngine.ObjectDependenciesRemover.RemoveObjectDependenciesByQuery(IEnumerable`1 queries)

Do you have any idea of what can be the root cause of that ? 
In my local code, it's working fine but not in production environment.

Could you help me please?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is it MVC or Portal Engine? Have you updated to 12.0.0 first and then installed the latest hotfix?

Comment: This isn't MVC, I use the portal Engine.
I update to 12.0.62

Answer (score 1):

Looks like not all of the Hotfix was applied correctly. Check and compare the Hotfix version on your local database and production. You can do it with this SQL query:

```
SELECT [KeyValue] FROM [CMS_SettingsKey] WHERE [KeyName] = N'CMSHotfixVersion'
```

If they differ, you would need to [apply it to the production database](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/installation/hotfix-instructions-kentico-12#HotfixInstructionsKentico12-Hotfixingyourproductiondatabase) as Kentico documentation says.